# How to Update EditText Value in another Activity while using Constant Class to store data

Tags: android

I need some guidance

**Question:**

I want to update quantity of an Item in ProductInformationActivity using EditText in CartActivity

**Overview of my program:**

I am using Constant class in ProductInformationActivity to store information for an Item like: Title, Qty, Cost, Total and then showing these details in CartActivity.

***View these screen shots:***

1. ProductInformationActivity : where i am accepting quantity by user first time.
2. CartActivity : where i want to allow user to update quantity of an item, which he has entered in ProductInformationActivity [here i am using EditText to accept new quantity]

**ProductInformationActivity.java:**

Whenever user click on Add Order button, i am storing Item Title, Qty, Cost and Total in Constant Class and then showing these values in CartActivity

Comment: 1st - why don't use database? 2nd - Do You want to replace new value with old? that is how it sounds. A little confusing.

Comment: yes i want to replace new value with old value, but i am accepting new value in CartActivity and old value i took in ProductInformationActivity, and there is no need to use database, that's why i have not used that @Gustek

Comment: So you want to replace **3** with **9** , am I correct, Pandey Ji ?

Comment: So You have 2 activities and one class with static variables where You store data, right? And You wish to synchronize data displayed in both activities? So if You make changes in one it will be updated in another?

Comment: @Lucifer yes Lucifer you are correct

Comment: @Lucifer hey Hritik ji please see my updated code and now tell me where i am missing??

Comment: @Lucifer buddy getting : Syntax error on token "String", @ expected

Comment: @ChulbulPandey Ok, at which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: @Lucifer Hritik Ji in this line: public static String getQuantity() and i am little bit confuse where i have to put this method in CartAdapter, for me also show it to place in CartAdapter, as you think my CartAdapter should look like

Comment: ok, you need to declare ` public static String getQuantity()` method before the last `}` terminate, got it ?

Comment: @Lucifer buddy i want it to update on EditText change in CartActivity

Comment: @ChulbulPandey Yes, I know, but as per Android System, only one Activity can stay on Screen at a time. So I gave you this solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29521/discussion-between-lucifer-and-chulbul-pandey)

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all Modify your qty EditText to static in CartAdapter.java as follows,

So, modify this line

> final EditText qty = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.qty);

as below,

> static EditText qty = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.qty);

Now create a public method in CartAdapter.java as below,

```
public static String getQuantity()
{
     if ( qty != null )
     {
          return qty.getText().toString();
     }
     return "";
}
```

Now in ProductInformationActivity.java

In onResume() method, write following line ( create a method if it is not there ),

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
     super.onResume();
     edit_qty_code.setText ( CartAdapter.getQuantity() ); // This line will get the modified EditText's value from CartAdapter.java class file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list with items

```
Constants.sItem_Detail
```

It is static and public so it is accessible from all classes anywhere.

When You are in CartActivity, ProductInformationActivity will be paused, stopped or destroyed. It is not displayed so You can not update it's view elements or at least You shouldn't do it.

In CartActivity You have TextWatcher,in onTextChanged method update value in Constants.sItem_Detail to a new value and in ProductInformationActivity You get it and set it in EditText in onResume method.

```
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = Constants.sItem_Detail.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview

        title.setText(item.get(com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_TITLE));
        qty.setText(item.get(com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_QTY));
        cost.setText(item.get(com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_COST));
        total.setText(item.get(com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_TOTAL));                        

        qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                int count) {

                        if (!qty.getText().toString().equals("")
                                        || !qty.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                                // accept quantity by user
                                itemquantity = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText()
                                                .toString());                      
//here You update value, You have item variable with current item
item.put(KEY_QTY, itemquantity);
//all object are always passed by reference so that is enough to update it

                        }      
                }
```

in onResume

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
     super.onResume();
     //get item to display
     HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
     item = Constants.sItem_Detail.get(id); //i don't know how You identify items, but here You need to get correct item from list.
     edit_qty_code.setText(item.get(KEY_QTY));
}
```

Comment: yes, show me some code how can i do this programmatically, you got it correct what i wanted

Comment: See updated. I don't know how You decide which item to display in ProductInformationActivity but I hope You understand an idea how it works.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new Intent.
2. Set the new data in as an extra on the intent.
3. Start the CartActivity with the new Intent.
4. In the CartActivity's onCreate get the data off the Intent and update the UI.